# Memory Management of Piece Table and Rope in Modern Text Editor

Tags: java, string, memory, data-structures

I know that we can use two stacks to implement Undo/Redo for text editors. For Piece Table, you can simply push the nodes that are going to be affected into the stack as mentioned [here](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/piece-chains) (Great write-up about Piece Table in general, btw). And for Rope, my understanding is that since Rope should be immutable, whenever there is a change, simply push the root of the old tree into stack as mentioned [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-ropes/):

"*Not only can text insertions and deletions be performed in near-constant time for extremely large documents, but ropes' immutability makes implementation of an undo stack trivial: **simply store a reference to the previous rope with every change**.*"

If this is the case, then Rope seems very memory intensive, and can quickly fill up your memory with a large file after a couple of modifications. How is this handled in modern text editors?

This leads to another question: What would you do if there is a 5GB file and you only have 2GB memory? I was thinking maybe use paging or dynamic loading, so when you scroll down it will discard some old text in memory and load more from the disk. Then how is this realized in Piece Table and Rope? Maybe we could serialize older part of data structure onto disk as we load more content and put into our data structure, but this just does not seem to be an optimal solution to me.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One  of the main advantages of immutable  objects is that they can share structures with each other. Because a structure  never changes,  the whole structure doesn't need to be copied; only the parts affected by the modification need to be duplicated. This means that only a relatively small amount of memory is needed for each addition. Here's a good explanation of how this is realized  with another tree-like structure: [Understanding Clojure's Persistent Vector](http://hypirion.com/musings/understanding-persistent-vector-pt-1).

Even with memory saving optimizations, very large files that don't  fit into RAM or a program's allowed memory space can still pose a problem.   To fix this, text editors will store parts of  the file that aren't directly being edited in some type of [swap file](https://www.linux.com/news/all-about-linux-swap-space). Some editors use their own virtual memory implementations to accomplish this, while others just pick parts of the file that are sufficiently far away from the cursor. As an (hypothetical) example, a rope's subtrees could be saved to a file if no modifications have been made on it for a certain amount of time.